# What happened when update .apk to android device?

Tags: android

i used eclipse "run as an android application" option to updating .apk(with new .so file) to phone, but found .so file were still old. What happened when updating apk to android device? Can .so file be updated also?

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate .so file again by build command of ndk .And then run your application again.It will then use new .so file. "run as an android application" makes new .apk of java as well as xml code but when you are dealing with c++ or c code the eclipse can't compile that code.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to compile your native code by running *ndk-build* command.

Then you need to make a *build.xml* file using `android update project`.

Before running `android update project`, find ID of the target you want to use for your project.

Run `android list targets` and find the ID for your target.

Now run android `update project --target your-target-id --name your-project-name --path /path/to/your/project.` It will populate your project with *build.xml* and *local.properties*.